# .NET Webservice = The surrogate pair is invalid

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

Getting the following thrown error when calling a web service. Have googled without any results other then people asking the same question.

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> The surrogate pair (0xD860, 0x27) is invalid. A high surrogate character (0xD800 - 0xDBFF) must always be paired with a low surrogate character (0xDC00 - 0xDFFF)."} 
System.Exception {System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
```

The web service returns a series of simple text fields from a view by running the view and opening a dataset and reading in the data and returning it as formatted XML.

**EDIT**

Was able to resolve this using the following regex which strips out the bad characters which happened to be MSWord/Excel characters

```
string re = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
return Regex.Replace(text, re, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might be happening is that:

- The XML file contains the bytes ED A1 A0 27.  According to chardet, this was most likely intended to be `эба'` encoded in IBM866.
- But it lacks an `encoding` declaration, so the parser assumes that it's UTF-8.
- The text gets decoded into the UTF-16 string D860 0027.
- This string is not valid UTF-16 because of the unpaired surrogate D860, so you get the exception.

Comment: Interesting. How do you know this?

Comment: Turns out it was bad characters as you say caused by copying between MSWord/Excel and then inserting into the database. I purged bad characters using the following, string re = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
            return Regex.Replace(text, re, string.Empty);